# Basic Authentication for SOLR (1.4) shard queries with SLL

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

We have SOLR (4.6) servers with basic authentication.

We want to do shard queries over them but we can't find a way to pass the authentication info, via the query or via SOLRJ...

We see a few threads on this issue open, but no resolution:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4470
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1861

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity

**Security for inter-solr-node requests** configuration point.

Comment: This does not seem to work when talking to shards, I udpated the info in my question. Thanks.